# Is there a way to put a lot of things in a fridge in an easy way?

Tags: the-sims-3

Or in any container for that matter?

After harvesting, I always end up having to drag every item in one by one. Also, is there a way to group the same item? After dragging and dropping, if I miss, it forms different stacks at times.

It seems so trivial but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Comment: I was about to say "just drag them using the mouse!" thinking that you were having the Sims do all the collecting which would take eons.  Then I read the question.

Comment: no, i figured that much out. also, if you ever accidently click the take all button on a fridge cotaining your full lifes harvest, draging them back in one by one is takin eons too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions here so please bear with me. If you knew this already and it doesn't help, it could help someone else.

While items are in your inventory, you can drag them on top of each other, however the stack are created based on the type of item, and in the case of food, their quality. You cannot always have different types of quality food on top of another. *This is dependant on which patch your running, some patches allowed it*.

Once you have the stack correct, it will create a square in the top left corner of the stack, which you can grab and then drag onto the fridge. This should add all the items to the fridge.

Sadly, there is no way to stack everything you want into one big pile and then add them to the fridge. i.e. You can't mix fish and tomatoes, or even tomatoes and potatos together. The stacks of the same item and group drag is the closest you will get.

Comment: the corner drag is what i was looking for. tried moving all 44 tomato at the same time with it and it worked a charm.

Comment: Origin claims I've spent 700 hours on the Sims since it was released on Origin, and I've literally never noticed that. Talk about sucky UX design.

Answer (score 1):

At the top right corner of the icon for stacked items, the corner is blue. So all you do is press the corner and drag.